# Why was the snaphat not awarded? Or why was it awarded incorrectly?

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash-2016

There have been a few cases in which the [snaphat](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/snaphat) was not awarded.

There have also been other cases in which it was awarded incorrectly, on old questions.

What gives?

Answer (score 18):

While the description of the hat is

> answer within 30 minutes of the question being asked, scoring 3 and getting accepted

what we actually implemented was

> Be the first to answer a question, receive 3 upvotes, and it is accepted

I've now corrected the implementation to be as expected. We won't remove the hats we've given out, and we will award due hats retroactively.

Out in the next deployment.

Comment: Should the 3 votes + acceptance all arrive within these 30 minutes, or is it sufficient that the answer is posted within 30 minutes of the question, and the votes can come later?

Comment: @Eran just the answer

Comment: You might need to check this again.  I just received a snaphat on [an answer](http://movies.stackexchange.com/a/65259/6236) where I was the third to answer, the third to reach 3 upvotes, and I answered 9 hours after the question was asked.

Comment: @BenMiller your hat was awarded 1h before the fix was built I think

Comment: It’s still not working as described: I answered [this question](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/33890/2594) not until 97 minutes after it was asked; yet I was awarded the Snaphat shortly after its acceptance less than two hours ago. No other answer of mine remotely qualifies.

Comment: And it happened again. I filed a [new bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288779/255554).

Comment: I didn't realise that http://meta.stackexchange.com/ is different to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/, so I effectively created a duplicate question there:  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340399/the-description-of-snaphat-seems-to-be-incorrect. In any case, my answer was more than 30 minutes after the question was asked. And the answer was on `2016-12-27 05:59:16Z`, which is after you said you fixed it.

Comment: I don't think that this is actually corrected... I just received this hat on Seasoned Advice for a question that I answered two hours after it was asked. Question was asked at 16:15 and I answered at 18:16. Has this just not been deployed yet? After a week?