# Can the description for Snaphat be changed?

Tags: bug, status-declined, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016

It seems that the [description of Snaphat](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/snaphat) is still not changed to match its implementation.

As quoted from [Why was the snaphat not awarded? Or why was it awarded incorrectly?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288529/why-was-the-snaphat-not-awarded-or-why-was-it-awarded-incorrectly):

> While the description of the hat is
>
> > answer within 30 minutes of the question being asked, scoring 3 and getting accepted
>
> what we actually implemented was
>
> > Be the first to answer a question, receive 3 upvotes, and it is accepted

Can it be changed as it's misleading?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed @Sklivvz next line

> I've now corrected the implementation to be as expected. We won't remove the hats we've given out, and we will award due hats retroactively.

So the description should now be correct. Changing it would be a bad thing.