# The Snaphat still doesn’t work as described

Tags: bug, winter-bash-2016

In [this answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/288529/255554), Sklivvz announced that in the next built after the 21<sup>st</sup>, 13:37 UTC, the Snaphat should be fixed and working as described.

Yet I was awarded the Snaphat twice without the conditions being met:

- [This answer](//german.stackexchange.com/q/33890/2594):

  - 23<sup>rd</sup>,   9:15: question posted
  - 23<sup>rd</sup>, 10:52: answer posted (97 minutes later)
  - 23<sup>rd</sup>, 15:42: other criteria fulfilled¹
- [This answer](//movies.stackexchange.com/a/65535/13707):

  - 23<sup>rd</sup>, 18:30: question asked
  - 24<sup>th</sup>, 10:37: answer posted (16 hours later)
  - 24<sup>th</sup>, 23:54: other criteria fulfilled¹

I do not know, how often builts are dispatched, but IIRC it was considerably less than three days. Therefore I assume that something is still not fixed.

<sup>¹ I know that this time is not supposed to count towards the thirty minutes in the description. However, this is when the hat could first be awarded and thus the crucial time at which the hat-awarding routine was still faulty.</sup>

Comment: FYI You can see the build number (which includes the deployment date) at the bottom left of every page

Comment: Hmm, that’s the 24th, which might still fit into this by six minutes. Now the question is whether there was any built in between.

Comment: I got it on [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288781/how-do-i-find-a-user-whose-name-contains-a-space/288782#288782) just now, when I posted the answer after 30 minutes.

Comment: Still not fixed. I got Snaphat just now on SA. My answer came over two hours after the question was asked. http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/77037/cooking-time-for-steaming-vegetables-al-dente As a note, I also was not first to answer... All I did was answer, get three upvotes and be accepted.

Comment: Try [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41279303/c-sharp-decimal-to-c-float-and-javascript-number/41308800#41308800) for size: I got Snaphat by editing an old answer (not posted within 30 minutes of the question) that subsequently got an upvote, pushing it to 3.

Comment: I'm looking to see what's going on with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are correct the hat was still being awarded wrong. There was a bug that we missed in the query that has now been fixed.  Can you spot the bug in the line of code causing the problem?

> `And DateDiff(minute, a.CreationDate, q.CreationDate) <= 30`

Basically, we had the answer creation date in the wrong position for the date comparison. Being in the wrong position it always resulted in a negative number.  The negative value meant that the hat was being awarded outside of the 30 minutes was supposed to be required.  The bug has since been squashed and the hat should now be awarded properly.

Comment: Just curious, are all the checks performed in the database level?

Comment: Also... are you a dev or CM? ;-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard the SQL is inline in the codebase.  Not a dev just someone who pokes around the code and knows sql.

Comment: So, you're kind of... Code Manager? :D

Comment: Shhhh @ShadowWizard don't give away all my secrets