# How do I find a user whose name contains a space?

Tags: support, moderator-tools, users

I was looking for any user with *Bruno Vincent* as username, on *Drupal Answers*, but using the diamond moderator tools I don't even get one user, even if [one account](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/16378/bruno-vincent) exists.

How do I search for a username containing a space?

Comment: Looks like that user has two spaces between his names which I assume was your problem :)

Comment: Duplicate of http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339745/73226

Comment: @MartinSmith Meta.se can't dupe to meta.so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your title question: **By typing with a space.**

For this specific case:

## It has two spaces.

Using just the regular-users user finder, I was able to find the user by typing two spaces instead of one. That was your problem.

I typed `bruno  v` and that user was the only one there.

Comment: I also copy-pasted the name from the user page, but it doesn't find it.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Like when you type with  extra  spaces in a regular post, it only shows one.

Comment: (There were extra spaces in          (<10 over there) this comment and ^that one)

Comment: That explains all. Yes, HTML doesn't normally shows two or more spaces.