# Why did it take so long for my Polymath hat?

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016

The hat description is:

> post at least one well-received answer on three different sites during Winter Bash (not including Stack Overflow)

I have posted these three answers on three different sites:

- Meta SE

[**How do I find a user whose name contains a space?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288781/how-do-i-find-a-user-whose-name-contains-a-space/288782#288782)

Score: 4. Accepted.

- Scifi SE

[**What was the Ludicrous Patents Office?**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/147924/what-was-the-ludicrous-patents-office/147925#147925)

Score: 23. Accepted.

- Puzzling SE

[**How did the dunces figure out who won?**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47126/how-did-the-dunces-figure-out-who-won/47127#47127)

Score: 1. Accepted.

I only received the Polymath hat *48* minutes after I got the upvote on the Puzzling answer (which was the last one).

## Why so long?

Comment: You got to wait for the 10 min intervals the hat program takes to run and give out hats

Comment: @PythonMaster I did. It's been a while since I got the upvote on the Puzzling one.

Comment: It's likely this particular hat does not run anywhere near as often as the others because it has to access databases for multiple sites instead of just one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wait time is probably due to the fact that the program waits a while to see if your answer is actually well-received or it's going to get pummeled by downvotes. You can't say the answer was well-received for the first 20 minutes. It's got to be well-received for a longer period of time.

Then the program gives you your hat when it reaches one of its 10 minute intervals that allows it to be run. And like @animuson said:

> It's likely this particular hat does not run anywhere near as often as the others because it has to access databases for multiple sites instead of just one.

Comment: Yeah, but *48* minutes?

Comment: Well yes. We have to be accurate yes?