# "Third Time's A Charm" has conflicting descriptions?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016

When I looked on the Winterbash 2016 page where they describe about each of the hats, there is [a description of "Third Time's A Charm".](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/third-times-a-charm)

Which says:

> hit the reputation cap on three different days

[image: Third Time's A Charm]

But on the [answer for regular hats on hat list post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288272/346728), there is something else:

[image: Changes in Winterbash Hat Answer]

**Which one should we follow to get the Hat?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **criteria listed on Meta** is the more updated one.

The criteria posted on Meta is the more accurate one since those are updated by users who have already gotten the hat. They are collated from the [Winter Bash chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50144/ye-olde-hat-shoppe) and [the secret hats Docs](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AFlWPYR7xnrQRsrVTS2Q_-sLhK7Ew1hLDz5oNKlu_n0/pub). In this case, [bluefeet mentioned it](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34296183#34296183) in the chatroom.

Similarly, there are also other hats with additional criteria that not mentioned in the Winter Bash page, such as Lifesaver (which requires at least an upvote) and conflicting criteria for Snaphat ([due to a bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288779/the-snaphat-still-doesn-t-work-as-described)).

That being said, the criteria listed on the Meta list and the official Winter Bash page doesn't differ a lot. Hitting the reputation *normally* means getting at least 200 reputation (unless you include bounties and accepted answers).

Comment: The reputation cap doesn't include accepts either. So getting 200 is a much easier target to meet (4 accepts for example is 60 points which would mean getting 260 instead of 200).